# keycode issue with javascript crossword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this [jQuery crossword](http://www.jesseweisbeck.com/crossword/) and trying to get it to work. The keycodes seem to have a strange issue. When you enter a word with 2 keys next to each other on the keyboard, it skips and doesn't type in the letter. I have little experience with keycodes so any help would be great.

```
switch(e.which) {
    case 39:
    case 37:
        currOri = 'across';
        break;
    case 38:
    case 40:
        currOri = 'down';
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    return false;
} else if (
    e.keyCode === 37 ||
    e.keyCode === 38 ||
    e.keyCode === 39 ||
    e.keyCode === 40 ||
    e.keyCode === 8 ||
    e.keyCode === 46) {                         
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
            currOri === 'across' ? nav.nextPrevNav(e, 37) : nav.nextPrevNav(e, 38); 
        } else {
            nav.nextPrevNav(e);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('input keyup: ' + solvedToggle);
        puzInit.checkAnswer(e);
    }
```

http://codepen.io/fcedillo/details/myEeEY/

Comment: I'm uncertain exactly what you mean, the codepen seems to work fine for me.

Comment: When you try to enter keys which are place beside one another (like 'q','w'.. 'x','c'..) in keyboard cursor jumps 1 block;

Comment: I think you mean if you type fast? yeah, it's a bug - the code needs to wait and confirm the letter has indeed been entered into the box but it doesn't